# Why does typing _ in the Python interpreter return True?

Tags: python, interpreter

I am getting very weird interpreter behaviour:

```
>>> _
True
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> type(_)
<class 'bool'>
```

I tried this because _ came up as a suggestion in Bpython, but it seems to work in the normal interpreter too. I am using

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 16 2013, 23:39:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Can anybody explain why _ is a substitute for True? Is it legacy, similarly to how ";" can be used to end commands, but is not necessary/encouraged?

EDIT: It seems to be random. This does not happen in a new terminal, but once I start working on something _ starts becoming true. What the hell is going on?

Comment: I get `NameError: name '_' is not defined`. Close the terminal, start afresh, try again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200020/python-get-last-answer

Comment: @thefourtheye That's what I thought too, but it seems to re-appear everytime I get back to work.

Comment: Note that if you do `>>> type(True)` and then `>>> type(_)` you get `<type 'type'>` as output, and not `<type 'bool'>`.

Comment: Related: [Assigning a value to \_ in Python/IPython interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17580289)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` will be the result of the last evaluated command - at interpreter start up there isn't any so you'll get a `NameError`... after that, you'll get the previous result... Try opening a new interpreter and doing `2 + 2`... you'll see `4` returned, then type `_`... eg:

```
>>> _

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    _
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> _
4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
2 + 1
Out[19]: 3

_ + 3
Out[20]: 6
```

`_` stores the last returned value. Try it out.

Answer (score 4):

`_` simply gives you the last result evaluated (in the REPL, not in an ordinary script). This can also mysteriously prevent objects from being [deleted immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129950/why-arent-anonymous-cpython-objects-deallocated-immediately).

Answer (score 1):

_ in the interactive interperter is usually the last output you received.

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> _
2
```

Note it only applies to outputs (printed data won't do).