# Type of an underscore character in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was playing with the `type()` method in Python, and came across this:

```
>>> type(_)
<type 'type'>
```

The 'type' of the underscore( _ ) character is `type` itself. What does that even mean?

Comment: [Is the single underscore "\_" a built-in variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-the-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python) or [Assigning a value to single underscore _ in Python/IPython interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17580289/2301450) or [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/2301450) or [Why does typing _ in the Python interpreter return True? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22269897/2301450)

Comment: That at some point Guido got Perl envy. :P

Comment: Presumably your previous line was also playing with `type()`, which means `_` was referencing some actual type from the last object you tested. This is equivalent to what you'd get if you did `type(str)` or `type(int)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside python interpreter, `_` is a special variable that returns output from previous line, so depending on the last line type of that variable value could be different.

For example,

```
>>> type(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> 1
1
>>> type(_)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(_)
<type 'type'>
```